# Error copying file for Docker instantiation

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to get a Docker application up and going from Github. I've changed one of the python files so I don't want docker to pull from Github, I want it to pull from a directory on the machine (Ubuntu) instead.

Original Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir requests==2.7.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir simplejson==3.7.3
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir six==1.10.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir twilio==4.4.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir twill==1.8.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir wsgiref==0.1.2
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir zope.interface==4.1.2
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir PyQRCode==1.2.1
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pypng==0.0.18
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir htmlmin==0.1.10
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir sendgrid==3.6.5

RUN wget -O master.zip https://github.com/thinkst/canarytokens/archive/master.zip?step=1
RUN unzip master.zip
RUN mv /canarytokens-master/* /srv
RUN rm -rf /canarytokens-master
WORKDIR /srv

CMD echo "Please use the docker-compose setup described at https://github.com/thinkst/canarytokens-docker"
```

My edited Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir requests==2.7.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir simplejson==3.7.3
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir six==1.10.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir twilio==4.4.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir twill==1.8.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir wsgiref==0.1.2
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir zope.interface==4.1.2
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir PyQRCode==1.2.1
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pypng==0.0.18
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir htmlmin==0.1.10
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir sendgrid==3.6.5

RUN cp /var/www/html/canarytokens-master.zip master.zip
RUN unzip master.zip
RUN mv /canarytokens-master/* /srv
RUN rm -rf /canarytokens-master
WORKDIR /srv

CMD echo "Please use the docker-compose setup described at https://github.com/thinkst/canarytokens-docker"
```

The only change I've made is changing the line `RUN wget -O master.zip https://github.com/thinkst/canarytokens/archive/master.zip?step=1` to `RUN cp /var/www/html/canarytokens-master.zip master.zip`

The original runs just fine and the application comes up fully functioning. The edited one gives me the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/html/canarytokens-master.zip': No such file or directory
```

I've tried putting the canarytokens-master.zip file in different locations including "/" and "/opt" - results in the same issue. I've changed permissions on the file so that anyone can read/write/execute - same issue. And I've confirmed that the file is definitely there. I can do a "cp /var/www/html/canarytokens-master.zip master.zip" manually at the command line and it will copy the file just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do with `RUN cp ....` is local to the container that is building the image, and nothing has to do with your host filesystem.

You need to place that zip file in the **context** of the build (tipically the dir where the Dockerfile is placed). Then do `COPY ./thefile.zip /srv`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatly, I'm having other issues with docker at the moment but as soon as those are sorted out I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Nope, that's not working. Moved the file into the directory with the Dockerfile and also tried moving it to the directory on up which contains the docker-compose.yml file. Both gave the same issue 

"mv: cannot stat './canarytokens-master/*': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'frontend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mv ./canarytokens-master/* /srv' returned a non-zero code: 1"

Comment: I've pointed to use `COPY` that is an special Dockerfile command (you cannot use RUN to put something inside a container). See [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: Worked perfectly!